# Unable to send total amount of bitcoin even after deducting the transaction fee what do I do?

Tags: transactions, blockchain, wallet, blockchain.info

Hi I recently imported a wallet to blockchain wallet from a backup, the wallet and everything shows up and everything but since the imported wallet is not protected by the backup phrase and not as secure as if the funds were directly imported into blockchains "My Wallet", when I try to send the total amount in my imported wallet to the blockchains "my wallet" it only allows me to transfer partial funds and not the whole amount even with the blockchain transaction fee deducted and set to regular the numbers don't add up, I have 4.56093409 in my imported wallet and with the fee of 0.0015431 it should allow me to send 4.55939099 however it only allows me to send something like 3.4889... so what do I do? also same thing happens when I try to transfer the funds to "my wallet" from under my security and addresses tab. Please help Thank you

Comment: I would try importing to a different wallet (eg a mobile wallet), and then attempt to 'send all' to your desired destination address. Otherwise this seems like it would be a question best answered by the blockchain.info customer service reps.

Answer (score 0):

i would go to coinb.in and manually broadcast the transaction to the network myself. this way you can have it set on the lowest fee, then go to viabtc.com and use their free transaction accelerator to give it a final push. works every time. GL